# Formatting date to specified format results in parse error: Unexpected character

Tags: php, datetime

Does anyone know why formatting this date results in the error message below.

```
var_dump((new \DateTime('Fri, 29 12 2019'))->format('D, d m Y'));
```

> Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Fri,
>   29 12 2019) at position 5 (2): Unexpected character

Comment: Since that's not a valid format, you need to use [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Sorry, this DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d m Y', 'Fri, 29 12 2019') results in 2020-01-03 16:20:45.000000 which is clearly wrong

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: Actually, it's clearly right. December 29, 2019 is a Sunday. It is picking the next Friday, since you're specifying Friday in the format.

Comment: The format should be "Weekday, day month year".

Comment: Correct. But your weekday does not match your day/month/year. So you will not get the response you expect.

Comment: Ah i see, the weekday is incorrect!